# What is the Equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy, quantum-gravity

I am refreshing my Physics skills and I cannot remember what this equation is. Will someone please tell me what this formula is for? It sort of looks like Stephen Hawkings equation for black holes.

$$ S = \frac{C^3 K A}{4 \hbar G}$$

Comment: And why could you just not have been a smart ass?

Answer (score 4):

It's written a little incorrectly, but it does look like [Hawking's formula for the entropy of a black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics#Overview).  The $C$ should be $c$, because it represents the [speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light); and the $K$ should be $k$ or $k_{\mathrm{B}}$, because it represents [Boltzmann's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant).  That is, it should be written as
\begin{equation}
  S = \frac{c^3 k_{\mathrm{B}} A}{4 \hbar G}.
\end{equation}
It's probably more common to see this written using [the Planck length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length) $\ell_{\mathrm{P}} = \sqrt{\hbar G/c^3}$, so that it is
\begin{equation}
  S = \frac{k_{\mathrm{B}} A}{4 \ell_{\mathrm{P}}^2}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Bekenstein-Hawking entropy](https://theoretical-physics-digest.fandom.com/wiki/Bekenstein-Hawking_entropy) of a black hole.
$$ S = \frac{k c^3 A}{4G \hbar} $$

It says that its entropy $S$ is proportional
to the area $A$ of its event horizon,
with a huge proportionality factor made up by the 
constants (Boltzmann's constant $k$, speed of light $c$,
Newton's gravity constant $G$, Planck's constant $\hbar$).